# How to get username (only) of the Apache?

Tags: server, bash, permissions, apache2

I am trying to write a Bash script for automatic chown'in files to the Apache2 user. But I need before to be 100% sure what is the username of it? I know that usually it is www-data. But, I need to be sure if, say, before the username has been somehow changed.

I am looking for a string that will return ONLY username of Apache2.

I know `# ps -aux | grep apache2` and many others, but they return a bulk of data and I just need a username.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: could you post that bulk of data ? use http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a great easy solution, that returns ONLY apache2 username:

```
ps -ef | egrep '(httpd|apache2|apache)' | grep -v `whoami` | grep -v root | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

Thanks.

Comment: A description of this command will be interesting for me. :)

Comment: @SpasSpasov: this command is a useful for more than only UBUNTU system, as it fetches even httpd (which is used in systems like Red Hat). This command checks a list of users for processes (httpd or apache2 or apache) and removes results (grep with flag -v, that inverts the results) for reserved system usernames (like whoami and root... btw, you can add other ones if you want, depending on the system (we are speaking now only about sudos). Next we are using the first header and awk'ing it (fetching only that column we need, and it is username in ps). That's it))

Comment: Only works if an http server is running, and only prints the username of the first http server.

Comment: @waltinator Not only running. For that here must be r fag. Here -e that means ALL the processes. Regarding the rest - you are correct.

Answer (score 3):

The username and group ID of Apache2 is set by a directive in the configuration file.  This is located at in the file `/etc/apache2/envvars`.

You can examine that file and notice that by default, as you suspected, it's `www-data`.  Also, as you can see from the file the usergroup is set by default to the same name.

Now that you have the effective user of `apache` you can use this to change the files to that user:

```
$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data myhtmldirectory
```

That will change the user and group owner of myhtmldirectory and all files and directories below it to `www-data`.

If you want to just change the user owner, drop the `:www-data` part which is for group.

A very sure way of having the correct usrID is:

```
$ awk -F= '$1 == "export APACHE_RUN_USER" {print $2}' /etc/apache2/envvars
```

This line will parse the envvars file for the current session that was started.

Comment: @Arsenii Sorry.  I mistyped the filename.  It's `envvars`.  I corrected the spelling in the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I found it, but... how to parse it easily (if it is even possible) and take $APACHE_RUN_USER from it in the Bash? Thanks

Comment: @Arsenii Now that you see from your configuration file, the filename.  You don't have to parse to get it.  You can change a group of files to that username by going to the directory and running this:  `sudo chown -R www-data  [html directory]`.  Change the `[html directory]` to the name of the directory with the files that you want to be changed to the apache2 user.  The `-R` part means all the sub-directories will be processed also.

Comment: I'll update my answer with a formatted example of what I just typed.

Comment: Thomas, thank you. I know how to do it. No problems with recursively  chowning the dir. The question is how to get the username of the Apache running in the Linux (if it has been changed (by user for some reason), the script MUST know it and set the right username, rather than just default www-data). Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can't change the usergroup while it's running.  When you start it it will be run by what is in the `envvars` configuration.  This is located when you start Apache.  It's part of the init.d process.  You can examine the `/etc/init.d/apache2` file to see how it's loaded.  But of course you could use an alternative by checking the `ps` of the apache2 while it's running.  the `-C` parameter specifies the comandname being checked.

Comment: Actually user and group who are set in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` can be different (for some reasons) from those defined in `/etc/apache2/envvars`.

Comment: You're right.  While on Ubuntu, the apache2.conf has the directive `User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}` with a notation above specifying where the change should be made, a person could override the way it's setup.  I was trying conscientiously specify how to use the Apache according to the modular configuration the Ubuntu installation.  Some changes can break Apache and the user might have to depend on using a different support channel... the modular setup might stop working.

Comment: `$ awk -F= '$1 == "export APACHE_RUN_USER" {print $2}' /etc/apache2/envvars ` it is great! Thank you! And thank you for your help! God bless!

Answer (score 2):

To find the names of the effective user of any process matching `apache2`, use:

```
ps -o euser= -C apache2
```

The `-o` option sets the output format.  In our case, we ask just for the effective useer name, `euser`.  The trailing `=` tells `ps` to suppress the normal header line.  This way, the output consists only of user names matching `apache2`.

I don't have apache2 running, so as an example:

```
$ ps -o euser= -C mount.ntfs
root
$ ps -o euser= -C atd
daemon
```

Comment: thanks, really, but.. it does not show anything with Apache. I have tried with just Apache (without ver determ. 2) and with 2.. nothing. No errors, neither usernames)) I will keep trying. Thanks

Comment: @Arsenii You're not seeing anything, most likely, because you have to have the command name typed in exact.  It can't be a capitol `a`... also it has to have the `2` in it as in `apache2`.  By the way, this command might fail because the server is initially started by the UID `root`.  Your script might choose the wrong userID before it changes by parsing the `envvars` file to what you have specified there.

Comment: The exact name is `/usr/sbin/apache2`, so the command must be `sudo ps -o euser= -C /usr/sbin/apache2`.